# Keeping a ListBox in a Grid white

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, grid, focus

Here you have a very simple standalone XAML file:

```
<!-- MyListBox.xaml -->
<Page 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainPage" Height="100" Width="525">
    <ListBox>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="42"></RowDefinition><!-- THE MAGIC LINE-->
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </ListBox>
</Page>
```

If you open this in Internet Explorer and click the `ListBox`, then it turns blue. However, if you remove `Height="42"` from `THE MAGIC LINE` then the box remains white when you click it. I have two questions:

1. Why does the presence or absence of `Height="42"` make a difference?
2. I would like to make the box permanently white even when `THE MAGIC LINE` contains an explict declaration of height. How do you do this?

Comment: why does your ListBox has a Grid as a Child element?

Comment: Well, the above toy application is an extremely simplified version of a real-world application that I'm working on. Changing the type of the child element from Grid to something else is not practically feasible, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

blue color is the default selection color for your listbox. the easiest way to get around is to set the following

```
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="42"></RowDefinition>
                <!-- THE MAGIC LINE-->
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </ListBox>
```

EDIT: your title is something different to the rest of your question. leave a comment if you want something different

Comment: Well, I've changed the title now.

Comment: does my style did what you want?